# What do 'xmt, xa, xc, d, c' keywords mean in html?

Tags: html, gzip

I opened gzip file of a cross reference file in linux.

The file contains various keywords.
I think that 'c' means comments but I don't know the others.

Could you let me know what those keywords mean?

```
<a href="/source/s?refs=whenNanos&amp;project=android" class="xa">whenNanos</a>
 <a class="xmt" name="isStatusBarKeyguard"/>

<a class="xc" name="ForcingNavHideManagerBySetting"/><a href="/source/s?refs=ForcingNavHideManagerBySetting&amp;project=android" class="xc">ForcingNavHideManagerBySetting</a> 

<a href="/source/s?refs=handler&amp;project=android" class="xa">handler</a>

<a class="d" href="#mHideNavManager">mHideNavManager</a>

<span class="c">// there is nothing to be done in initializer now..</span>
```

Comment: Those aren't HTML keywords, they're strings. Those strings are being used as the `class` attributes of HTML tags. If you want to know what those classes are being used for, you need to give more information about where this file came from. Or you could read the relevant CSS or JavaScript code that might be making use of those `class` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There is CSS code somewhere that the page is using that looks *something* like this:

```
.xc {
  font-size: small;
  color: #333333
}
.c {
  font-size: small;
  color: #008080;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

By the way, those are really terrible class names.